# How to find repeating elements in the following grid?

Tags: list-manipulation, table, tuples

Consider the following table:

```
grid1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5};
grid2 = {0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.1, 1.2};
grid3 = {0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4};
tuples = Join[Tuples[{grid1, grid2, grid3}],RandomReal[{1, 2}, {6*6*5, 1}],2];
```

I do not have `grid1, grid2, grid3`, only the resulting `tuples`, but I want to find them. If they did not contain duplicating points, it would be, e.g., simply

```
grid1 = DeleteDuplicates[tuples[[All,1]]]
```

but it would remove the extra 0.2 and make things wrong:

> {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}

Is there any quick approach to the extraction of these grids?

Actually, I simply need to find the duplicates in each of the grids.

**Edit**

An ugly way would be like this:

```
grid1 = tuples[[All, 1]] // DeleteDuplicates
tableoccurences=Table[Length[Select[tuples, #[[1]] == grid1[[i]] &]], {i, 1, Length[grid1], 1}]
occmin = tableoccurences // Min
grid1 = Table[
   Table[grid1[[i]], tableoccurences[[i]]/occmin], {i, 1, 
    Length[grid1], 1}] // Flatten
```

and so on. `tableoccurences` counts the number of times each element of the grid is present in `tuples`. The main problem is that the approach assumes that `occmin` corresponds to the element that is present only once.

Comment: Do you know the lengths 6, 6, and 5 before-hand, or does this need to be inferred from the structure of `tuples`? And can you clarify what "Actually, I simply need to find the duplicates in each of the grids." means?

Comment: @march : it is unknown.

Comment: @march : I needed to find what element is present more than one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we know that `tuples` is constructed from `ngrids` input *grid*s and *if each grid has at least one non-repeating element*, we can get the duplicates and their counts in each of the grids using

```
extractDuplicates = 
  Map[l |-> Select[GreaterThan[1]] @ Normalize[#, Min] & @ Counts[#[[All,l]]]] @
  Range @ #2 &;

ngrids = 3;

extractDuplicates[tuples, ngrids]
```

> ```
>  {<|0.2 -> 2|>, <||>, <|0.35 -> 2|>}
> ```

We can get the input *grids* and their lengths as follows:

```
extractGridLengths = 
  Map[l |-> Length @ # / Min @ Counts[#[[All, l]]]] @ Range @ #2 &;

extractGridLengths[tuples, ngrids]
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 5}
> ```

To get `grid1`, `grid2` and `grid3`,  we can use a combination of `ArrayReshape` and `Extract` to get the *grid*s:

```
extractGridPositions = 
  Extract @ 
  Map[m |-> {Splice @ ReplacePart[Table[1, #], {m} -> All], m}] @
  Range[#] &;

extractGrids = extractGridPositions[#2] @
    ArrayReshape[#, 
     Append[Length @ First @ #]@ extractGridLengths[#, #2]] &;

extractGrids[tuples, ngrids] == {grid1, grid2, grid3}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

***Another example***:

```
SeedRandom[1];

numberOfGrids = RandomInteger[{2, 9}]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

```
randomGridLength := RandomInteger[{1, 8}]

randomGrids = Table[
 While[Min@Counts[$g = RandomInteger[3, randomGridLength]] > 1]; $g, 
 numberOfGrids]
```

> ```
> {{2, 0, 0, 0},   
>  {0, 1, 2},   
>  {1},   
>  {0, 2, 3, 3, 3}, 
>  {3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0}, 
>  {0, 2, 1},   
>  {2, 3, 0, 2, 2},   
>  {3}}
> ```

```
Map[Length] @ randomGrids
```

> ```
>   {4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 3, 5, 1}
> ```

```
randomPadding = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {Times @@ Map[Length] @ randomGrids, 1}];

randomTuples = Join[Tuples@randomGrids, randomPadding, 2];


randomTuples // RandomSample[#, 10] & // Column
```

[image]

```
extractGridLengths[randomTuples, numberOfGrids]
```

> ```
>  {4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 3, 5, 1}
> ```

```
extractDuplicates[randomTuples, numberOfGrids]
```

> ```
>  {<|0 -> 3|>, <||>, <||>, <|3 -> 3|>,   
>   <|3 -> 3,  0 -> 2|>, <||>, <|2 -> 3|>, <||>}
> ```

```
extractGrids[randomTuples, numberOfGrids] == randomGrids
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you know the lengths `Length@grid1 == 6`, `Length@grid2 == 6`, `Length@grid3 == 5`, then you can take advantage of the structure of `Tuples` to brute force this:

```
grid1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5};
grid2 = {0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.1, 1.2};
grid3 = {0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4};
tuples = Join[Tuples[{grid1, grid2, grid3}],RandomReal[{1, 2}, {6*6*5, 1}],2];

tuples[[;; ;; Length@grid2 Length@grid3, 1]]
tuples[[;; Length@grid2 Length@grid3 ;; Length@grid3, 2]]
tuples[[;; Length@grid3, 3]]
```

will result in the three grid lists.